# Is it possible to hook up a MySQL database with python

Tags: python, mysql

Is it possible to hook up a MySQL database with python program if the MySQL database is made in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: MySQL is not "made" in PhpMyAdmin - PhpMyAdmin is a tool that handles MySQL. And yes, you can use Python to connect to MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely yes. You can use libraries called [SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy)
, [Sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) or [MySQL Connector/Python from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/).

I recommend Sqlite3. I used it with my flask application, worked perfectly and easy to use.

Comment: Sqlite3 can be used to connect to a MySQL database? Please enlighten me...